# NVMe hotswap / hotplug with linux and amd working?

Tags: linux, amd, nvme

Has someone got nvme hostwap/hotplug working on linux with amd? We use RS500A-E10-RS12U (ASUS) and hotplug / hotswap is not working. If I remove devices it wont disappear in lsblk and If I add devices they wont be recognized in lspci or lsblk.

I wanna find out if this is software based issue or something that can be fixed via bios/settings or a bios update.

Any tips or tunings to get this working? If I reboot the node, every new nvme is working. Im using 5.13 Kernel.